# mod_rewrite missing trailing affects link system

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to make my site multilingual by implementing language codes (en/es) into the URL. So far it has worked well, all the links automatically switch to the language you select. Except for the home page.

A link saying `mydomain.com/en/staff.php` will be in the right language, and all the links will automatically work (en/home.php, for example).

The one that doesn't do that is the home, if I forget the trailing slash.  `mydomain.com/en/` works perfectly fine while `mydomain.com/en` (no slash) doesn't update the links properly.

Is there a way around this using mod_rewrite? Or will I have to write out the links manually in the HTML?

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/?$  index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(\w+)\.php  $2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a rule to enforce **trailing slash** Place this rule in your root .htaccess:

```
DirectorySlash On
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule [^/]$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/$  index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]{2})/(\w+)\.php$ $2.php?lang=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: This is leading to a redirection loop now :( I've added my complete modrewrite file in case it matters.

Comment: There is no reference to `.errordocs/404.html` in above rules? Where is that coming from? Do you have other rules not shown here?

Comment: No, there are no other rules. I think the problem is that it adds a /mydomain/ folder in between, which should not be there.

Comment: If there are no other rules then `.errordocs/404.html` has to coming from somewhere since my rules have no reference to that string. Some rules/config might be in `httpd.conf` file OR may be in your code. I can;t guess without more info.

Comment: Also these rules have no reference to `/mydomain/` folder as well.